# Positioning elements on a webpage

Tags: html, css

I have included a link to a picture to help explain my question: http://i.gyazo.com/b1e319cda4b7c21a5072156f5bd7c590.png

Im trying to position the red div exactly below the blue one. The problem is that the top container which you can see at the top of the picture, has a height of 100%. The blue div then has a height of 300px and is positioned with top:100%.

How can I get the red div exactly under the blue one? I almost just need to be able to do: top: 100% + 300px;

Thanks!

Comment: The white space is just empty by the way.

Comment: Please post your relevant HTML and CSS. The image link is 404, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, added proper image. Code shouldn't be needed in my opinion with the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could do top: calc(100% + 300px);  ?

Comment: Wow, never knew you could do that. How awesome! Cheers !

Comment: Also, I think would be better to use **top: 100%; margin-top: 300px;** since **compatibility**. Or if margin-top is not working then margin-bottom in negative , for example _margin-bottom: -300px_ Cheers too! :) @George

Comment: Historically, [`calc` support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) isn't great, and even current implementations have pretty glaring bugs.

I would think using margins like your second suggestion would be a better choice.

Comment: Yeah, I just recalled that using **calc** method is not very compatible. For example on Android tablets and some other devices it won't work. So use **margins** instead! @George

Answer (score 0):

1. Put both the red div and the blue div in a single div container.
2. Apply the absolute positioning to the outer container, and keep the inner divs static (as in, remove absolute positioning).
3. Remove margins between divs with margin: 0;